# How to join two tables in Spring and Hibernate using a criteria query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to join two tables in a Spring + Hibernate application by using a criteria query but it doesn't work. I have included my tables and DAO code below.

> **User** table

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------
| Column                                              |    |
 ----------------------------------------------------------
| id                                                  | PK |
| address                                             |    |
| mobile                                              |    |
| otp                                                 |    |
| password                                            |    |
| user_name                                           |    |
| user_type                                           |    |
 ----------------------------------------------------------
```

> **Tracking** table

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------
| Column                                              |    |
 ----------------------------------------------------------
| id                                                  | PK |
| location                                            |    |
| product_id                                          |    |
| qrdate                                              |    |
| serial                                              |    |
| userId                                              | FK |
 ----------------------------------------------------------
```

> **DAO** code

```
Criteria crit = currentSession().createCriteria(QrCodeList.class);

Criteria prdCrit = crit.createCriteria("user");
prdCrit.add(Restrictions.eq("serial","F1VKCva01"));

List results = crit.list();
```

Running the criteria query always throws an error.

Comment: Error messages contain important hints about what's wrong. Never just say "it gives an error" - include the exact and complete error message. So, what exactly is the error message you are getting?

Comment: What is `QrCodeList`? Which table does it correspond to? You can get to the `User` table from the `Tracking` table through the `userId` column but how do you expect to go from the `User` table to the `Tracking` table by creating a criteria query on `User` and then specifying a `serial` number to find?

Comment: it will shows org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: user of: com.virtual.applets.mpark.entity.QrCodeList

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an alias

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria("user");

crit.createAlias("user.tracking", "tracking")
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("tracking.serial","F1VKCva01"));

List results = crit.list();
```

You need to have an association from `User` to `Tracking`.

Comment: when i  using your code it  shows local variable crit may not been initialized kindly tell me what will do?

Comment: @sathish Sorry, I fix it.